# Using non Google Analytics tag in URL alongside regular Google Analytics tags

Tags: url, parameters, google-analytics

I'm having some issues with Google Analytics URL parameters. Prviously I've built URLs with the Google Analytics URL Builder. these have enabled me to track where visitors to my site have been coming from, how successful various marketing campaigns have been etc.

Recently, I've started using another tag in the URL, one which has nothing to do with Google Analytics, but acts to alter the telephone number on my site when the visitor arrives on it. For example, I'll add &ctcc=adwords onto the end of my tracking URL, and a specified phone number will appear on my site when the user comes through so I can track how many calls my adwords spend has generated.

However, when I've been using this ctcc code, Google Analytics no longer seems to be tracking the traffic numbers to my site :(

Any idea how I can incorporate the two parameters into the URl, and ensure that they both work as expected?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say "Google Analytics no longer seems to be tracking the traffic numbers to my site" do you mean that you are not getting pageviews at all, or you are just not getting traffic source information? Also, some before and after urls (feel free to blank out your site name) would be helpful for debugging.

Comment: Hi there, I'm getting the pageviews through GA, but I'm not able to attribute them to a source i.e. referrals, campaign etc. An example of the URL would be http://www.mywebsite.com/special-offers/special-offer.phtml?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=my%2Bspecial%2Boffer%2B130313&ctcc=adwords

Comment: I tested out those tags on a site with a working GA setup, and it looks fine. The utm_ parameters can co-exist with other tracking parameters with no problem generally, so I'm not sure what the difficulty with your setup is, but I think it's not the ctcc code. Can you think of anything else? Also, if you are comfortable posting your site's URL, I'd be glad to look at the installation and see if I can debug it.

Comment: I think it has something to do with ctcc. It was working before I started using this code. I've done some investigating, and it seems that when I click a tracked link with the ctcc included, its changing the URL compared to when its not got the ctcc. With ctcc (which gets stripped out) the GA parameters are separated by a semi-colon: http://www.cruisenation.com/offer.phtml?utm_source=google;utm_medium=cpc;utm_campaign=adwords      without ctcc, the parameters are separated by ampersands, as they should be! Weird.....???!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a problem with how your server is redirecting traffic with a ctcc query parameter. Look at the following request and its response headers:

[image: Request]

[image: Response]

So the ctcc parameter is used in some server side tracking (as best as I can tell), and the server is set up to redirect & strip ctcc whenever it gets a request with ctcc. Not being familiar with the system in use, I can't provide details, but you need to reconfigure the redirects to stop changing `&` into `;`. It's the replacement of ampersands with semicolons that is messing up your GA data.

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks so much for that! I'll take this information back to the administrators of the system I'm using and see if they can help out.